# Cannot specify url in .env file vue cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm referring to the [documentation about environment variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) in vue cli 3.

I'm able to set it up and get simple variables to show up but my url in the .env file doesn't show up.

Contents of the .env file:

```
FOO=bar
VUE_APP_SECRET=secret
API_URL="https://staging.something.org"
```

Here is how I'm viewing the env:

```
console.log(process.env)
BASE_URL: "/"
NODE_ENV: "development"
VUE_APP_SECRET: "secret"
```

The `API_URL` is not visible, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code).

> Only variables that start with **VUE_APP_** will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. You can access them in your application code:

Your `VUE_APP_SECRET` is accessible because it's prefixed with `VUE_APP_`. Use `VUE_APP_API_URL` instead of `API_URL` to access it in your frontend.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just missed that somehow in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Since CLI 3, Vue recognizes variables in dotenv only when adding the prefix VUE_APP_

When making changes, restart CLI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).